# Appcelerator Titanium: how to record video?

Tags: android, titanium, video-capture, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

How to record video in Appcelerator Titanium and store in a specific location ?

I am using an Android 2.3.6 device.

This gist: https://gist.github.com/832488 does not seem to work as suggested / expected. It starts the video capture intent

`var intent = Titanium.Android.createIntent({ action: 'android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE' });`

as an `activityForResult` but the callback in

`Titanium.Android.currentActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, function(e) { ... });`

is never called, none of notifications in code appear and the video is stored in some default location.

The KitchenSink app does not have any video example[for Android], only a camera example code. It does have a [record_video](https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/KitchenSink/blob/06d3f89623597981fa1b7dc0bab5bf65e61fc29d/Resources/ui/common/phone/record_video.js) module for android video capture but it only manages to capture a picture. The line

`mediaTypes: Titanium.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,`

does not seem to be working

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that its all a 'context' play.

Found the reason at http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/137709/startactivityforresult-and-callback-function-problem#244265

- The problem really is the use of heavyweight windows in Android by the SDK which means a new Javascript context.
- A heavyweight window is always created when you open a new window from inside a TabGroup.

So, the gist at: https://gist.github.com/832488 works, given that the camera is not launched from within (inside) of a tabgroup.